# How to remove supervisor BIOS password from Toshiba laptop

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords

My laptop has a supervisor password set that I need to erase or remove. It is not a BIOS password nor is it a HDD Password because BIOS password is not set and in BIOS menu, the supervisor password is "registered". Any Ideas how to get rid of it? I already know the battery removal for 15 minutes technique but I don't want to remove battery as it is shottered in the motherboard and I don't want to void my warranty. My laptop is Toshiba P855-S5200. Please Help!!

Comment: There may be a jumper you can remove to disconnect the battery.

Comment: I looked at tutorial on youtube where they say the "XXX" markings on board besides the RAM.. I searched the whole motherboard but no luck I didnot find any signs with "XXX"

Answer (score 1):

Some brief searching led me to this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbXW6-PngZk) that shows that some laptops (and this is a Toshiba in the video) have open points on the board that can be jumpered (connected with a wire) to clear the password.  If your laptop has these points exposed like such in the video give it a try.

I have not tried it myself but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a jumper reset, where you short two of the pins. The steps I take when trying to find what's on the motherboard are that I first go to the manufacturer's website and try to find a parts list, then I would go to the motherboard manufacturer's site to find an exact layout. There they'll certainly tell you whether you have jumper reset pins or not. Since motherboards are all so different in layout, design, and markings, you have to be your own expert of your components. If there are not jumper reset pins, the only way to reset is taking out the battery.

By the way, what do you mean the battery is "shottered"? Typically taking out the battery for 1 or 24 hours is the most surefire way to reset the bios.